# Paypal window not showing multiple items

Tags: node.js, express, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm creating my own cart and then using Paypal smart button for the payment in Angular.
For multiple items to handle, I'm uing items array in `createOrder` method at the backend in Express.

```
function arrayOfItems() {
        art_details.forEach((item, index) => {
          let sku = item.message;
          let currency = priceDetails.collPriceL[index];
          let tax = priceDetails.taxAmtL[index];
          let quantity = item.quantity;

          let items = [
            {
              name: "Collection",
              sku: sku,
              description: '' + item.collid,
              unit_amount: { currency_code: "CAD", value: "" + currency },
              tax: { currency_code: "CAD", value: "" + tax },
              quantity: quantity,
            },
          ];
          return items;
        });
      }
```

I'm now using `arrayOfItems()` as items in createOrder:

```
 const request = new checkoutNodeJssdk.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    request.prefer("return=representation");
    request.requestBody({
            intent: "CAPTURE",
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  currency_code: "CAD",
                  value: ...,
                  breakdown: {
                    ...
                  },
                },
                soft_descriptor: orderkey,
                items: arrayOfItems(),
                shipping: {
                  ...
                },
              },
            ],
          });
```

Suppose I'm creating order for 2 items. `art_details` contains array of items I need to purchase. My order is creating successfully but the Paypal window doesn't show the items in right side. (it should appear as a dropdown of items).

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Log your actual request body JSON string, so it can be tested

Comment: @PrestonPHX No worries. I had it fixed now. Issue was in `arrayOfItems()`. I now created an empty array of items and pushed each obj into it. Now it's working. Thanks